# Animate Button When View is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to have a button move using a UIView animation when the view loads. A nearly identical animation works in another view when a button is pushed. This is my ViewDidLoad

```
HTMLButton.hidden = NO;
HTMLButton.enabled = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect HTMLRect = HTMLButton.frame;
                     HTMLRect.origin = CGPointMake(HTMLRect.origin.x, HTMLRect.origin.y + 70);
                     HTMLButton.frame = HTMLRect;
                     NSLog(@"Animation Called");
                 }];
```

The NSLog does compile but no animation at all. Can I not call the animation here or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you to anyone who can help

Edit: I used the same Animation called from a separate IBAction in a different button, the animation still doesnt work

Comment: Have you tried putting this code in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Have you checked that `HTMLButton` is actually set to something and not `nil`?

Comment: `HTMLButton` is attached to a button in my .nib file but it is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear internals might be interfering with the animation. There might be other tasks in viewDidLoad so your button is not even fully loaded when you call frame change animation. I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but if it happened to me I would definitely give this a try:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.2; //Or you may play with it further
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             animations:^{
                 CGRect HTMLRect = HTMLButton.frame;
                 HTMLRect.origin = CGPointMake(HTMLRect.origin.x, HTMLRect.origin.y + 70);
                 HTMLButton.frame = HTMLRect;
                 NSLog(@"Animation Called");
             }];

});
```

This will delay the animation call a little (it is not possible for users to understand 0.2 sec lag) so your viewcontroller is in a waiting state rather than doing any initialization.

Comment: put an extreme delay then like 5 secs. if it is still not animating then you should look for other problems with your button init.

Comment: I have no idea why this worked but I removed `HTMLButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];` from my .m and it works. Your last comment is what made me look into the initialization of it so thank you.

Comment: In the comments you wrote the button is linked in the .nib file. You don't re-alloc controls that are defined in the .nib or storyboard, that's not correct. They are already allocated and init'ed when nibs are loaded.

Comment: Im used to initializing everything from when I learned Java, it was just a force of habbit